# How much time elapses between two single photon interactions between two electrons?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics

When two electrons interact, this can be viewed, in the context of quantum field theory (Feynman diagrams), as two real electron lines entering the diagram and two real electrons leaving the diagram:

[image]

The amplitude of the process can be obtained by adding all possible diagrams. Only the shown diagram will suffice if you want to get a crude amplitude. But won't the two electrons, before leaving each other, interact a second (or third) time? Ain't this the case if the electrons move slow enough, in which case we can use classical electrodynamics to account for the classical static electric field? I guess so because quantum electrodynamics is used only in relativistic processes.

Comment: Did you really mean to write  “between two photons” in the title?

Comment: Feynman diagrams do not show classical trajectories. The “time between” the two vertices is *all possible times*. The premise of your question is flawed.

Comment: *quantum electrodynamics is used only in relativistic processes* That’s not true. It’s common in a QED calculation to look at the non-relativistic limit as well as the ultra-relativistic limit.

Comment: @G.Smith I didn't mean it but I did...You answered my question already in a comment...

Comment: @G.Smith So in evaluating the path integral all times and all positions are considered, as is logically in the relativistic context (spacetime)? In the classical variation problem (evaluating the action), only variations in position are considered. Or not?